# php twitter post image not going - working

Tags: php, twitter

I'm trying to send a status with an image on Twitter. The status gets posted succesfully, but the image does not show up. Why is this?

Are there any mistakes in my code? The status does update successfully.

```
require_once 'twitteroauth.php';


$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_SECRET);
$content = $connection->get('account/verify_credentials');
$image = 'logo.png';
$connection->post('statuses/update', 
    array(
        'media[]'  => "@{$image};type=image/jpeg;filename={$image}",
        'status'   => 'message text written here',
    ),
    true, // use auth
    true  // multipart
);
```

Comment: Are you sure the path to the image _logo.png_ is correct?

Comment: yes path is correct #Bono

Comment: Just noticed you're specifying type=image/jpeg, whilst your logo is a png. Try changing that? This might also help you: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/statuses/update_with_media

Comment: update but still not working
my image is here : $image = 'http://careertracker.net/pt2.jpeg';
and twitter wall : https://twitter.com/butlersusan4

Comment: Just to be sure, you're using the image from your local file system right? I'm not sure twitter can read it from a website.

Comment: no  : http://careertracker.net/pt2.jpeg 
is live image check please it's on jpeg format

Comment: Download it to your folder in the project and use it from there.

Comment: i think image path is not big issue image permission is '777' so it is not problem... problem is in the code

Comment: Can you please check what's the response you get? Did you try to upload a media and then attach it to the `statuses/update` as a `media_id`?